# infinite sum of measures estimate

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I got stuck solving the following problem:

Consider a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and a non-negative measurable function. Furthermore, suppose $f$ is bounded and integrable. Show that $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \mu(\{x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2^k}\}< \infty$$
I tried to the following with Tonelli's Theorem $$\sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} \mu(A(k)) \leq \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \int f \cdot \mathbb{1}_{A(k)} = \int \sum_{k = 0}^\infty f \cdot \mathbb{1}_{A(k)}$$
where $A(k) = \{x \in X: f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2^k}\}$. But this is not really useful since $(A_k)_k$ is not a partition of $X$. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A_k=\big\{x\in X:f(x)\geq2^{-k}\big\}$, $D_1=A_1$ and $D_k=\big\{x\in X:2^{-k}\leq f(x)<2^{1-k}\big\}$. Then it follows

(1) $\mu(A_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k\mu(D_j)$,

(2) $\{D_k\}$ is a partition of $X$, and

(3) $\int_{D_k}f(x)d\mu\geq2^{-k}\mu(D_k)$.

By these observations, we have

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\mu(A_k)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\sum_{j=1}^k\mu(D_j)\\[.4em]
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\mu(D_j)\sum_{k=j}^\infty2^{-k}\\[.4em]
&\leq2\sum_{j=1}^\infty2^{-j}\mu(D_j)\\[.4em]
&\leq2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\int_{D_j}f(x)d\mu\\[.4em]
&=2\int_Xf(x)d\mu<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: very helpful! Nice solution